# Input too large for RSA cipher

Tags: rsa, puppet, lets-encrypt, pkcs#7, eyaml

I am using two Virtual Machines sat on a single server. One VM is my Puppet Master(puppet server) and the other is my Puppet Agent. I am using PCKS7 RSA encryption to pass a secret token to my Puppet agent from the Puppet Master. I am using an .eyaml file within my control repository to keep the encrypted token in.

How I am encrypting the token:

I first start off with creating the keys for eyaml on the Puppet master. To do this I run:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml create keys --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/private_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/public_key.pkcs7.pem
```

Once I have run that I then go and change the permissions of the directory and the files, to do this I run the following three commands:

```
chown -r puppet:puppet /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml
```

```
chmod -r 0500 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml
```

```
chmod 0400 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/*.pem
```

From here I am then ready to encrypt the token. For this I run the following command but with the key and value filled in:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/eyaml encrypt -l  'insert key to be encrypted here' -s 'insert value to be encrypted here' --pkcs7-private-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/private_key.pkcs7.pem --pkcs7-public-key=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/public_key.pkcs7.pem
```

I then take the encrypted value and place it in my eyaml file within my control repository `/contol-repo/data/secrets/nodes/example.example.com.eyaml`

This file then looks something like:

```
---

letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare::api_token: ENC[PKCS7,<Encryption here>/Sc=]
letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare::email: 'example@googlemail.com'
```

Deploying the Code:

I am using r10k as well, so if I have made changes to the control-repo each time I pull from github after I will run `r10k deploy environment production -pv` 
Once I have run that I then go a head and run `puppet agent -t --no-noop` on the Puppet Master. Once that has run and succeeded I then go over to my puppet agent and run the same command  `puppet agent -t --no-noop` . This time I find my self with an RSA cipher error.

The Error that I am seeing is the following:

```
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: hiera-eyaml backend error decrypting ENC[PKCS7,<Encyption here>Sc=] when looking up letsencrypt::plugin::dns_cloudflare::api_token in /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/data/secrets/nodes/example.example.com.eyaml. Error was input too large for RSA cipher. on node example.example.com
```

I have had this working in the past with the exact same process as I have placed above.

Any help on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated, I have been trying to work out the best way to resolve this but I am unsure.
Thank you.

Comment: I'd guess that you are using a demo RSA public key instead of the one you should be using. You'd get this error if the key / modulus is smaller than the one used by the private key (`example.example.com` ?).

Comment: I am using a DNS private token with this, I have just not put this in here nor the encryption that I get from it once it has encrypted. I am also using example.example.com on here instead of the actual node name / domain or email address. @MaartenBodewes

Comment: I'm a cryptographer, not a puppet expert. As such I do know that RSA input is smaller than the modulus size, and encrypting twice won't work for raw RSA encryption. However, that should not be a problem when using PKCS#7 which (usually?) performs hybrid encryption, where an AES key is encrypting the data, and the key is then encrypted using RSA.